# import google spreadsheet to site page and apply site styles to a table tag

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-sheets

**Task: import google spreadsheet to site page and apply site styles to a table tag.**

is it possible make using JQuery, ajax call or need other technology?

Need some tips or examples, i cant find this.

**UPD**

I guess

if make import spreadsheet as html, inspect code and you can see id="content" and inner you table, maybe this jquery code can working:

$('#result').load('-google spreadsheet html import link- #content');

it's right?

Comment: Did you try checking out the [Simple example of retrieving JSON feeds from Spreadsheets Data API](https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample)?

Comment: yes i will try, not working. test spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqmhWQ_A7q_adDl1eEdWSWlvczVvTkF5d1hmQ2VaR0E&usp=sharing atom link https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0AqmhWQ_A7q_adDl1eEdWSWlvczVvTkF5d1hmQ2VaR0E/od6/public/basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess was right, this code working — spreadsheet inserting «one in one» and can apply different style:

```
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#result').load('-google spreadsheet html import link- #tblMain');
                });         


                </script>
```

All much easier than I expected:)

Comment: Please don't include your API_KEY's. They are unique, and not meant to be shared with the public.